# Finding volume of solid under $z = \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ above the region bounded by $x^2 + y^2-y=0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral

> Find the volume of the solid that is under the hemisphere $z=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ above the region bounded by the graph of the circle $x^2 + y^2-y=0$.

I solved this problem using limits of integration $0$ to $\pi/2$. The graph and double integral are found in this image:

[image]

This was done using symmetry, yet if I use $0$ to $\pi$ as limits of integration (see this image below), then I do not get the right answer, what goes wrong ? How can it be done properly without using symmetry?

[image]

Note: the right answer is approximately $0.60$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Comment: The limits have to be from $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$ in order to get the same answer since the angle is measured from the y axis.

Comment: Right, that makes sense to me measuring from the y axis, but measuring from the x axis it doesn't seem to work for me, why is that ?

Comment: I think I get it now, because it is symmetric about the y axis, the boundaries should be from -pi/2 to pi/2 to have an equivalent expression, my way would of worked if it was symmetric about the origin. Correct me if I'm wrong